# Creating popups in Mapbox GL for Leaflet in R-Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, mapbox

I'm finding it impossible to add the popups that are possible to add in JS via R's Leaflet.MapBoxGL library. This library lacks native popup functionality.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how I might augment the code so as to do this in R.  I'd rather not scrap my work and start over in JS if at all possible.

```
  library(shiny)
  library(leaflet)
  library(leaflet.mapboxgl)

  ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Panel"),
    leafglOutput("map")
  )

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    map = createLeafletMap(session, 'map')
    session$onFlushed(once = T, function() {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(quakes) %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
    options = pathOptions(pane = "background_map")) %>%
      addMapboxGL(style = "mapbox://styles/thirdhuman/cjzn4e0xz1ed41cnq6ni0qckl",
                ,group = "Rural"
                ,layerId = "Rural"
                ,popup = paste0(
                         "<b>Country: </b>")
                ,option = pathOptions(pane = "Rural"))
       })
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Error:

```
  Warning: Error in addMapboxGL: unused argument (popup = paste0("<b>Country: 
  </b>"))
```

I'd like to figure out some way to make this work.  Above is minimal example, but my real code has multiple layers of these MapBoxGL style layers.

Comment: Why not just add the popup when you add the markers: `addMarkers(popup = paste0("<b>Country: </b>"))`?

Comment: I get the following error:
"Warning: Error in guessLatLongCols: Couldn't infer longitude/latitude columns"